# why when i have a np.power in my function jax.grad can't give me the derivitives?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, jax

I want to train a simple linear model. these below x and y are my data.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = 2 * x + 3 + np.random.randn(100)
```

f is a function that calculates mean square error over all data.

```
def f(params, x, y):
  return np.mean(np.power((params['w'] * x + params['b'])-y , 2))
```

```
from jax import grad
df = grad(f)
params = dict()
#initialize parameters
params['w'] = 2.4
params['b'] = 10.
df(params, x, y) # I will do this in a loop (implementing gradient decent part
```

this gives me an error:

```
FilteredStackTrace: jax._src.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on the JAX Tracer object Traced<ConcreteArray
```

when I clear `np.power` code works. why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAX cannot compute gradients of `numpy` functions, but it can compute gradients of `jax.numpy` functions. If you rewrite your code in terms of `jax.numpy`, it should work for you:

```python
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = 2 * x + 3 + np.random.randn(100)

import jax.numpy as jnp
def f(params, x, y):
  return jnp.mean(jnp.power((params['w'] * x + params['b'])-y , 2))

from jax import grad
df = grad(f)
params = dict()

params['w'] = 2.4
params['b'] = 10.
df(params, x, y)
# {'b': DeviceArray(14.661432, dtype=float32),
#  'w': DeviceArray(7.3792152, dtype=float32)}
```

You can read more details in the [`TracerArrayConversionError` documentation page](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError).